# RegEx to find characters starting and ending with a hashtag / pound sign?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string

Given as string like:

```
"I #am# taking my big #brown# dog for a #walk# in the park"
```

I need a regex that would return this collection of strings:

```
#am#
#brown#
#walk#
```

It would be nice if it would ignore standalone hashtags (i.e. if it finds a space before the next "#", skip it and look for the next match).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What language or tool?

Comment: also called the number sign if you aren't in the USA.

Comment: I'm using VB.NET. Thought this would be language-agnostic, but I could be wrong, thx.

Comment: /(#[^#]*#).*/ perhaps close?

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to capture the marked up words:

```
(?<=#)\w+(?=#)
```

This uses look-arounds to *assert*, but not *capture* the surrounding hash chars.

Using `\w` means that only word characters will be found (ie hashes with whitespace both sides are ignored)

Use your application vide to iterate through the matches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My content is in xml.  My question was in an effort to avoid using xslt, but I ended up going that route, after all.

Comment: Using regex for XML is a minefield. Some sort of XML tool is probably netter

Comment: How would you change this if you wanted to include the # at the end ?

Comment: @JacobIRR `(?<=#)\w+#`, but if you know it’s going to be ending with a `#` your app can add it.